# Rewrite rule based on query string

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I'm trying to redirect to the base url (`www.example.com`) requests that have a particular query string (when `option` is `com_estateagent`).

I've tried the following syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_estateagent$
RewriteRule .* index.php [R=301, L]
```

But it gets ignored.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
The url that I want to change is something like this:
`http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.php?option=com_estateagent...`

Comment: So you're trying to reroute a component? Why don't you create a router.php in your component folder? That's the Joomla way and it could address your needs as far as I understand them.

Comment: actually these are old links that google still remembers after I removed them... I'm trying to re-route them to my homepage to avoid 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the RewriteCond directive, wouldn't something like this work?

```
RewriteRule ^/.*option=com_estateagent /index.php[R=301,L]
```

Comment: It should work, are you sure mod_rewrite is loaded and working?

Comment: yes, it loaded and working, also I put that line on top of the .htaccess file, so it shouldn't conflict with other rules...

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_estateagent
RewriteRule .* subdirectory/index.php? [R=301, L]
```

Notice, the `?` after `index.php`. That's important if you want to drop Query Parameters on redirect.

Comment: @tampe125 Add the sub directory to the rule.

Comment: I'd wish to redirect it to the root